# I found the answer to my question but only by chance, because of the wording of the answered question was completely different. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

It wasn't that the answered question's wording was poor as such, just that it attacked the same problem from a very different angle, and so it contained none of the keywords I would have used when searching for the answer to my problem.

Should I:

1. Edit the original question to include my version of the question as well (so that the original answer isn't lost? (so "How do I X" becomes "How do I X OR How do I Y")
2. Ask my version of the question, then self-answer with a link to that question
3. Some other course of action?
4. Do nothing

Comment: Personally, I like option 2

Comment: @DarrenH You do link link-only answers? That's a shame.

Comment: Closely related: [Should I post a question that I'm going to immediately close as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307615/should-i-post-a-question-that-im-going-to-immediately-close-as-a-duplicate)

Comment: Agree with this last comment. And also closely related would be another question linked to from that one, [Deliberately opening duplicate questions as search targets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290768/deliberately-opening-duplicate-questions-as-search-targets)

Answer (score 5):

Your course of action may depend on the question but providing a link only answer should never be done.

I think you should ask your question with your own title and words, then flag for a moderator to:

1. make it a duplicate of the other question (if you cannot vote for that yourself), and
2. perform a merge of your question with it.

Comment: On top of what has been suggested here: you can also write a comment under your question explaining the purpose of your question. This may can prevent confusion of the readers and/or down and close votes.

Answer (score 3):

## Post your own question.

- You should first of all post a new question with the proper wording. However, you should add a note that describes the purpose of your post, to avoid negative feedback, such as close votes and potentially even down-votes.
- If you think that there is room for improvements to the existing answers, you should provide another answer to your own question, and of course credit the initial post with a link. However, don't do it if the existing solutions are of good quality.
- If you have the necessary reputation, cast a vote to close your question as a duplicate. If you don't, raise a moderator flag and after making it a duplicate, merge it with the other question.